# jade why it is always unexpected token <

Tags: pug

```
doctype html
link(rel='stylesheet', href='bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css')

script(type='text/javascript', src='bower_components/angular/angular.js')
script(type='text/javascript', src='/app/app.js')

body(ng-app='app')
  div(ng-controller='testCtrl')
    div hi
    div {{ test }}
```

the debugger keep complaining :

> ```
>  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <        angular.js:1
>  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <        app.js:1
> ```

I realize that my script tag is not closing. in the debugger it shows like this.I am new to jade

```
<script type='text/javascript', src='bower_components/angular/angular.js' </script>
<script type='text/javascript', src='/app/app.js'  </script>
```

both of the script tag is missing **>** before `</script>`

Comment: do you mean your developer tools in the browser? then check, if the js files are really loaded

Comment: nope, let me improve my questions. a minute

Comment: which jade-compiling thing do you use?

Comment: should be the latest one because npm install jade.. How do i check that?

Comment: look at package.json - it would be maybe also helpful to see the code with which you actually render the jade file (node.js)